# Python firebase realtime database set method promise?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to this. Trying to get response on successfully adding data to firebase real-time database from python. Successfully added but unable to get promise response, unable to find documentation also. Can someone help!. below is my code for set the data

```
data = {
    'Phone': 1234567890,
    'Name': 'TestUser',
    'Email': 'testuser1@gmail.com'
}

root = db.reference('/users')
user = root.child(User_mobile).set(user_data)
print("response", user);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.db), the `set` method doesn't have a return value. If the call completes, assume the write succeeded.

Alternatively have a look at `set_if_unchanged`, which *does* have a return type, but is a *conditional* write operation.